# como des-habilito un TextBox y como lo habilito mediante un botón?

Tags: c#

Si quiero des-habilitar los TextBox como lo hago y luego que se presione el botón los textBox se habiliten para que se pueda escribir en ello.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//se desactiva
        {
            textBox1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//se activa
        {
            textBox1.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Al iniciar puedes establecer como activo o inactivo el texbox, esto lo haces en el constructor poniendo textBox1.Enabled = false;

Comment: y hacer que aparezca un valor por defecto por ejemplo 1 sin tener que escribirlo una vez que se habilite aparezca un 1 ayuda por favor y gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Enabled = true;
            textBox1.Text = "holamundo";
        }